# Leaflet (non-geographic): Zoom and keep center of the screen

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am doing a custom Leaflet map, with three levels of zoom. It isn't a geo map, just the interior of a building.

Right now I am creating a proof of concept before the artist starts to work on the final images. I generated the tiles from some blueprints but I am having an issue with Leaflet.

When I zoom using the mousewheel, the tile (location) where the mouse was position, becomes the 0,0 of the screen, which is not the expected behavoiour. If i set `scrollWheelZoom: 'center'`, the center of the screen goes to the 0,0 when I zoom in, but still it isn't what it is expected.

I would like to copy Google Maps behavouir, when you zoom in, the center is still the center in the next level.

You can see the proof of concept here: http://tarantino.com.ar/maps/test.html

(Zoom level 0 is black, 1 is red, 2 is blue)

Comment: Your blueprints are not correct positioned. `var marker = L.marker(mymap.getCenter()).addTo(mymap);
mymap.on('move',(e)=>{marker.setLatLng(mymap.getCenter())})` Add this to your map and then you see that you zoom always to the current center and not everytime to [0,0]

Comment: Why my blueprints are not correct positioned? Anyway, I add that marker, and the zoom is still wrong.

Comment: Edit: I added this line, thinking it was missing, but it didnt work either `mymap.on('zoomlevelschange', (e)=>{ mymap.panTo(marker.getLatLng()) });`